# Как пройтись по массиву и то что в ключе вставить в html тег?

Tags: javascript, html

Как на чистом `js` пройтись по массиву и то что в ключе `head` вставить в `html` класс `head` ?

Сравнение ключей `id` и `item` обязательно одновременно, записей может быть много, тоесть если они совпадают то делать вставку

```js
let items = [
  {id: 12, item: 123, head: 'Запись 1'},
  {id: 33, item: 765, head: 'Запись 2'}
];
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div data-id="12" data-item="123">
    <span class="head"></span>
  </div>
  <div data-id="33" data-item="765">
    <span class="head"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сперва собрал все HTML-элементы `.head` в отдельный объект, в котором ключами являются строки `id + разделитель + item`. Теперь через цикл по массиву, из `id + item` каждого объекта можно собрать такую же строку и проверить его наличие в созданном объекте:

```js
let items = [
  {id: 12, item: 123, head: 'Запись 1'},
  {id: 33, item: 765, head: 'Запись 2'},
  {id: 55, item: 765, head: 'Запись 2'},
];

/***/
let map = {};

document.querySelectorAll('.items .head').forEach(head => {
  let data = head.parentNode.dataset;
  let key = get_key(data.id, data.item);
  
  map[key] = head;
});

/***/
items.forEach(obj => {
  let key = get_key(obj.id, obj.item);
  
  if (key in map) map[key].textContent = obj.head;
});

function get_key(id, item) {
  return id + '@_@' + item; // <-- Здесь могла быть любая другая строка,
  // которая наверняка не встречается в id, item. В том числе и котик ^_^)~
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div data-id="12" data-item="123">
    <span class="head"></span>
  </div>
  <div data-id="33" data-item="765">
    <span class="head"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Такой подход, конечно, не прям универсальный, т.к. в одном свойстве могло бы случайно оказаться `111@_@22` а во втором - пустая строка, и оно бы совпало с другим объектом, где реально есть значения `111` и `22`. Но это маловероятная мини-уязвимость.

---

Существует еще CSS-селекторы атрибутов. `[data-id="x"][data-item="y"] .head` означает: Найти все `class="head"`, которые находятся *где-то внутри* (потому что *пробел*) элемента, у которого *одновременно* (отсутствие пробела) есть два таких атрибута со значениями `x` и `y`. В данном случае, значения атрибутов передаются в виде переменных ([шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```js
let items = [
  {id: 12, item: 123, head: 'Запись 1'},
  {id: 33, item: 765, head: 'Запись 2'},
  {id: 55, item: 765, head: 'Запись 2'},
];

/***/
items.forEach(({id, item, head}) => {
  let select = `[data-id="${id}"][data-item="${item}"] .head`;
  let element = document.querySelector(select);
  
  if (element) element.textContent = head;
});
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div data-id="12" data-item="123">
    <span class="head"></span>
  </div>
  <div data-id="33" data-item="765">
    <span class="head"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

(подозреваю, будет работать чуть медленнее из-за сложного селектора и поиска для каждого элемента массива. Без измерения - не узнать)

---

`({id, item, head})` называется [«деструктурирующее присваивание»](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Разбирает прилетевший в виде параметра объект и дает переменным значения, имеющиеся у свойств объекта с теми же названиями.

Comment: А если использовать querySelectorAll ? на всякой случай если копии будут в html  теги с атрибутами data-id и data-item, чтобы в всех местах подставилось

Comment: @Squeli47 Во втором варианте это решится легко. Останется заменить `if (element)...` на `element.forEach(e => e.textContent = head);` А в первом, с дополнительным объектом, посложнее. Например, вместо присваивания `map[key] = head;` собирать их в массив `(map[key] || (map[key] = [])).push(head);`, а вместо `textContent = obj.head;` сделать такой же forEach по массиву.